# Cloud explorer Debug evaluation issue

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, webapi, azure-appservice

We have a Web API deployed in Azure App Service.

When I am debugging it using Cloud Explorer in visual studio, it is behaving strange.

Code

```
 var userData = GetUserData(user);
    
    if(userData == null)
    {
    
     // controll comes here even userData is not null
     return NotFound();
    
    }
```

Debug point going inside if statement, even variable **userData** is not null.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating the variable with == null, use **IsNullOrEmpty** or **IsNullOrWhiteSpace** Methods for checking not only the empty string, also null values and whitespaces if given.

```
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userData))
```

or

```
  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userData))
```